# VM migration on Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I wish to run a web server on Azure. My concern is whether Azure migrates virtual instances (VMs) between physical servers for performance optimization purposes and if so does it provide some kind of guarantees on the performance hit that migration incurs?

Answer (score 0):

For VM performance and availability, you can use Availability Sets to be covered by the 99.95% SLA. This guarantee works due to the use of Fault Domains and Upgrade/Update Domains across physical machines spread across server racks.

- More info here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-manage-availability/

If you just want to run a web app without having to worry about the VM, you can also use Azure's PaaS offering (just endpoint access) instead of IaaS (full VM access).

- More info here: http://azure.microsoft.com/services/app-service/web/

Hope that helps!